# Unable to map the currency field with the Rollup Summary

Tags: apex, formula-field, roll-up-summary

I am unable to map/link my currency filed with the roll-up summary in my Sandbox and Dev environment.

But all the thing is working fine in my test account (created new SF account with my gmail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have both mutli-currency and Advanced Currency Management enabled? If yes, then it appears rollup will not be available, please see and vote for this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqMq).
One suggestion is the rollup helper on the app exchange found [here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI), or there is also my favorite rollup tool that is available on [github](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) and explained in this blog post [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/04/09/new-declarative-rollup-tool-release-community-powered/).
Also just saw this [blog](http://www.salesforceweek.ly/2015/02/how-to-create-roll-up-summaries-using-flow.html) post on using flow to create rollups.